# Why does using a turbofish with into give "wrong number of type arguments"?

Tags: rust

This works:

```
use std::error::Error;

fn main() {
    let _: Box<dyn Error> = "test".into();
}
```

But this gives an error:

```
use std::error::Error;

fn main() {
    let _ = "test".into::<Box<dyn Error>>();
}
```

```
error[E0107]: wrong number of type arguments: expected 0, found 1
 --> src/main.rs:4:27
  |
4 |     let _ = "test".into::<Box<dyn Error>>();
  |                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ unexpected type argument
```

Why?

Comment: I'm assuming that the definition of whatever `"test".into` returns doesn't have a type definition but in the first example you're setting the type of your variable so no issue

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This comes from the [`Into`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.Into.html) trait definition:

```rust
pub trait Into<T> {
    fn into(self) -> T;
}
```

As you see, `into` has no generic parameter, but it comes from the trait definition itself. The proper fully-qualified syntax then would be:

```rust
use std::error::Error;

fn main() {
    let _ = Into::<Box<dyn Error>>::into("asd");
}
```